# How to fetch data in a Single SSRS report using Multiple Dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I was trying to create SSRS report with a country map and a table. Country Map for showing total Number of Cases state wise and a table to show the total number of Cases in the whole country on the Top Middle side of the Report. Both (Map and Table) Using Different Datasets.
When I run the report to preview the data, It gives me an error:

**The Endvalue expression for the map uses an aggregate expression without a scope. A Scope is required for all the aggregates used outside of a Data region**

However, I have also tried to use the first dataset to calculate the Sum of all cases in the country.
But it shows the data in the table state wise not the Complete Sum.

**=Sum(Fields!Total_Cases.Value)**

I have read some issue similar to this topic but unable to implement them.
For displaying total cases in the table I have also mention the dataset name but not getting result.

**=(Fields!Total_Cases.Value, "Dataset2")**

Please suggest the correct way..

Comment: I am not saying it is badly written, I just don't fully understand the issue. If you could provide some screenshots of the report and report groups, it might help.

Comment: Hi @Marko, Actually I was using 2 dataset's in my report and both these datasets are not linked with each other. Report contains one Map and a table. Both the Map and table using different datasets.  When I run the report, it throws  an error like "The Endvalue expression for the map uses an aggregate expression without a scope. A Scope is required for all the aggregates used outside of a Data region".
 Hope this time I am able to clear the picture.